# How to select a column from table/collection using odata URI?

Tags: mongodb, rest, get, odata

I am using mongodb and odata.
I want to select name field alone for particular user id. (i.e) select name from userdata where userid=1;

```
/*my collection schema - userdata*/

{
    id:number,
    userid:string,
    name:string,
    data:object    
}
```

I tried `http://localhost:27017/userdata?$format=json&$filter=userid eq '1'&$select=name`

Instead of getting name file alone I got whole object/document that matches userid=1. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I tried on a [OData reference service](http://www.odata.org/odata-services/)  with http://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/People?$format=json&$filter=FirstName%20eq%20'Scott'&$select=FirstName and got the desired result. So the command syntax is not the problem here.

Comment: So your question "What I am doing wrong here?" can't be answered based on the available information, as we can't see your code.

Comment: @jps thanks for replying back. The database schema and model which I used is mismatching (i.e) I forget to add name field in my model, so It is giving the whole collection. I changed it, now it is working fine for me

Comment: you're welcome. If there's no problem anymore, you can either write an answer and accept it, or just delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoted the problem after the comment from @jps.

The issue is not with query, the problem is with data model which I am using is mismatching with my database schema (i.e) I missed out name field in model, so it is returning whole collection.

Now model is fixed, so the service is responding back with names for given userid.